# Equivalent to lxml's `text` and `tail` for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, lxml

Say you have xml like this:

```
<foo>
  bar
  <baz>qux</baz>
  buzz
</foo>
```

If you were to load this up in python's `lxml`, you'd be able to do something like

```
print foo.text # bar
print foo.tail # buzz
foo.text = "hello"
print tostring(foo) # <foo>hello<baz>qux</baz>buzz</foo>
```

Is there any similar way to access and manipulate the text in this way with jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
var xml = '<foo>hello<baz>qux</baz>buzz</foo>';
var doc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $doc = $(doc);

var $foo = $doc.find('foo');

console.log($foo.prop('firstChild').nodeValue)
console.log($foo.prop('lastChild').nodeValue)
console.log($foo.prop('outerHTML'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qrQR5/)